# Checking battery level in the background with a service limitation on Android O

Tags: android, background-service, android-8.0-oreo

I have an app which monitors battery level but I'm concern how will work on upcoming Android O version with service limitations in the background. Any hints or ideas will help me a lot.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start a foreground service to monitor the battery or you can schedule a periodic job. Periodic jobs have a min period of 15 minutes.

Comment: Yes, I know about scheduler job, but with it, I can not show to a user current battery level.

Comment: There are only these two options, no more.

Comment: There are many apps on Google Play store where one of the main features is battery level monitoring, so they will be useless on Android O.